# PHP mysql database not populating values into tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a simple PHP program that stores many rows of data into tables. But when I run the program it only populates one row of the 10's of thousands of rows I am trying to populate. It also doesn't give any `mysql_errors`.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$tickets = explode(' ', file_get_contents("tickets.txt"));
foreach($tickets as &$ticket){
    $handle = opendir($ticket);
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
        if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
            $raw_data = file_get_contents($ticket."/".$file);
            $raw_data = trim(str_replace("Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close", "",          $raw_data));
            file_put_contents($ticket."/".$file, $raw_data);
            $file_temp = fopen($ticket."/".$file, "r");
            while(!feof($file_temp)){
                $line = fgets($file_temp);
                $data_array = explode(',', $line);
                $date = $data_array[0];
                $open = $data_array[1];
                $high = $data_array[2];
                $low = $data_array[3];
                $close = $data_array[4];
                $volume = $data_array[5];
                $adjclose = $data_array[6];
                $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$ticket` VALUES  ('$date','$open','$high','$low','$close','$volume','$adjclose')");
                if(mysql_query("SELECT FROM $ticket WHERE `date`='$date'")){
                } else {
                    echo "ERROR";
                }
                echo $date.$open.$high.$low.$close.$volume.$adjclose."<br>";
                if(!$query){
                    mysql_error();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Look at the load data infile action http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html to import your data.

Comment: Are you reading the file on a Mac or was the file created on a Mac?

Comment: Also, is `echo $date.$open.$high.$low.$close.$volume.$adjclose."<br>";` returning what it's supposed to?

Comment: The file was created on PC. It is a simple csv file. The echo $date.$open.$high.etc... was me trying to figure out if the values were changing throughout the foreach.  @SharkofMirkwood

Comment: And are they changing correctly? If not you could try putting `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);` before reading the file...
Otherwise (not sure it makes a difference) put a semicolon at the end of your SQL - the lack of it could be causing a problem possibly.

Comment: You can count how many times your `while(!feof($file_temp))` or any of the other loops are looping through and `echo` it on page. The handmade ways of debugging I mean!